# For mobile webkit, how can I make the horizontal menu bar scrollable when you touch/drag it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, webkit

Let's say I'm on the standard iPhone 4.

My menu bar is 2000px in width.  When the user touches and holds on the menu div, he can move his finger left/right, and the menu bar will move. This allows the user to browse all of the menu's items using his finger. (Scrolling left/right)

How can I make that in javascript/jquery?

It's like the Google Images webview (go there on your phone). You're able to swipe left and right to navigate each image.

Except...I want it to be a menu bar, with no "snapping".

Comment: do you mean make it work for another device?

Comment: I just want a horizontal scrolling menu bar. The user can scroll it using its thumb to navigate all the items. (because the width of the phone cannot show all the items)

Comment: Have you tried the swipe events in http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html?

Comment: @ChristianVarga Nope. Is this the solution? Also...I don't want to use JQuery mobile. I only want to use Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very very basic example. It should get you moving in the right direction though.

```
$('body').bind({
    'touchmove': function(e){

        $('.menu_bar').css({
            'left': e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX
        });

    }
});
```

To get where you're headed you'll need to also store the touchstart coordinates, the .menu_bar start position and then use a bit of math to move the bar relative to it's position rather than just snapping to the finger position each time like the example above will do.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Touchmove is the event that is fired by mobile Safari when you drag your finger about the screen. Also, touchstart and touchend.

Comment: You could also try the hammer plugin. It adds support for most stuff, including desktop for testing. But I'd try just building it yourself as it's quite a small part of your site, it's a bit overkill having so much code. Here it is anyway: http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Comment: Thanks will. Is "touchmove" part of the original jquery?

Comment: No, touchmove is just an event that javascript (and therefore) jQuery have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little confused by the question but I believe the answer is just to use

```
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

This will work for iOS5 devices and give you a small scroll bar when active (i.e. when scrolling)

Otherwise you could try this plugin: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Or: http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/
(which is multi-device)